To create a v-btn-toggle whose buttons are aligned vertically, instead of horizontally
I am currently trying to create a quiz, using VueJS and Vuetify. I am trying to arrange the answers the user can select vertically. To do that, I am trying to use the v-btn-toggle component. However, the v-btn-toggle component's buttons are aligned horizontally by default. If possible, I would like to know how to arrange them vertically.
here is my layout:
<v-btn-toggle v-model="toggle_multiple" multiple>
    <v-btn>
         Answer 1
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn>
         Answer 2
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn>
         Answer 3
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn>
        Answer 4
    </v-btn>
</v-btn-toggle>

and here is my style, as recommended in this question :
.v-btn-toggle{
    flex-direction: column;
}

the answer I've tried gave me weird results, as the answers only display up to the second answer and a half, as such :
my disappointment
Any help is appreciated.
edit:
I've found out my problem comes from vuetify's default css
.v-btn-group--density-default.v-btn-group {
  height: 48px;
}

And it's preventing me from making a group button that's more than 48 pixels in height.
I didn't want to change vuetify's default settings (for portability issues), so now I am trying to override the default css. Unfortunately, even though i've added css of my own, the page still uses vuetify's css over mine as shown in this image


The disappointment looks like an overflow, inspect the CSS of the container. Otherwise, CSS tricks has a flexbox guide too, good reference. Otherwise, a [repro] is very welcome for further help.

here is an example, https://codepen.io/Gouillaime/pen/mdggzpm, but I couldn't manage to recreate the bug. But I've created a fresh new project to test it, and it happened again. I'm at a loss here.

I'm thinking about vuetify's default project's css, I'll try to look into that

The codepen works perfectly on my side. Sure it's not a monitor/viewport issue on your side? Try on a bigger screen on another browser maybe.

Yes, the codepen works for me too, the only place where it doesn't work is in my live project

I guess there is something wrong with my setup but I can't find it

Inspect the CSS you have there, no magic sauce.

alright, I found it,
the problem comes from vuetify's default settings, I did a bit of digging and I found that in the vBtnGroup's default css
.v-btn-group--density-default.v-btn-group {
  height: 48px;
}

Basically, by default, the button group's height won't go above 48 pixels
I don't really want to change vuetify's default settings, so is there a way to override it without changing vuetify's default settings? I've tried redefining the height directly but it didn't work

grah, no backspace nor code in the comments is really annoying

Use CSS to have a higher specificity: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp That way no need to change the defaults of Vuetify. Also, you probably do not need !important, try using a lower specificity. As for comments, you can still use backticks for code, even tho not critical here.

oh wow, fast answer, thanks, I'll try it out and tell you

I've tried putting my style as inline style and it is working, thanks! I'm just a bit frustrated by not being able to define style with the class, but I'll take what I have

You probably can, give a try to this one button.v-btn-group--density-default.v-btn-group or maybe an ID. Another great example for the specificity: https://specifishity.com/

thanks, it's working with the id

I'm still a stackoverflow newbie, so since I found half of the answer by myself, should I answer the question myself?

Be careful because you can only have 1 unique id on a page. Having a dynamically generated id is not a bad thing. Usually, you post your answer and your helper posts the answer. You accept + upvote his answer, while you have an upvote from his side and a solution on yours. It's a win-win. You could post your own answer and accept it, but there is nothing given back to the helper. Hence, you can use it as a self-answer, those are usually done alone with no interaction to have a way to remember to do things by yourself.

Some people like to post an answer straight and then update it, I rather solve it in the comments first and then post my answer. Same result in the end.

OP found that Vuetify has some default 48 pixels height.
After double-checking that the whole thing works as expected regarding flexbox, we narrowed it down to overriding the default values locally thanks to CSS specificity.
OP has a working solution by targeting the given button with
#my-button-group {
  height: auto;
}

Another alternative could be to use button.v-btn-group--density-default.v-btn-group.
